# How to replace last numerical value from a string if there is any

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have some files say A.atdf, B.atdf etc. When I parse these files into dataframe, I get a column called "TEST_TXT" where values are like this -

```
0    100 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCI
1    100 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCI
2    100 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCI
3    100 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCI
4    101 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCO
5    101 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCO
.....  .....  ...... ...........
```

But for some ".atdf" files, I have also **TEST_TXT** like this -

```
0    100 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCI 140
1    100 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCI 12
2    100 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCI 76
3    100 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCI 204
4    101 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCO 139
```

i.e random numerical values appended to the name.

I want to delete the appended numbers **"140", "12", "76"** etc from the names and make it plain **"100 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCI", "101 Continuity_PPMU_mV XSCO"** etc for the files it has numerical appended.

I have written a python code which does this but it loops through the series and it is not quite elegant.

How can I remove the appended numerical values from the series wherever it occurs(it does not occur in all the parsed files, only a few)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.replace`:

```py
df['TEST_TXT'] = df['TEST_TXT'].str.replace('\s+\d+$', '')
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HKOIub/2) which shows that the replacement logic working.

Comment: This is really great. I applied to my code and works like charm. I understand df["TEST_TXT"].str.replace() part. Can you please explain a bit more about the regex and how did you come up with it, such that it only deleted the later appended numerical value?

Comment: The regex `\s+\d+$` simple says to match one or more whitespace characters followed by a digit, which immediately is followed by the end of the column.

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks for the redirecting me to regex demo website. Great resource.

Answer (score 1):

Can use either str.replace the digits at the end of string or can split with the same and select right index.

```
#df['TEST_TXT']=df['TEST_TXT'].str.replace('\d+$','')
df['TEST_TXT']=df['TEST_TXT'].str.split('\s\d+$').str[0]
```

Comment: Hi. I think the logic is pretty same to the Tim's answer and I believe it would work just fine too. Thanks a lot. Upvoted.